# Why can't proteins make copies of themselves?

Tags: proteins

Why is it impossible for proteins to make copies of themselves?

Comment: Because they have no "blueprint" to work off of. DNA is the "set of directions" used to make new proteins.

Comment: I mean you could argue that proteins *do* make copies of themselves, just not *de novo*.

Comment: It is not impossible. It simply didn't evolve that way.

Comment: I really don't think questions of the type "why is the world like this" are either answerable or useful. If you can offer a biological alternative and argue that it was equally feasible, that is a different matter.

Comment: If the question was "Are there proteins that are able to self-replicate?" everyone would be happy I suppose. @tesgoe you should rephrase your post. You could say that DNA is able to self-replicate to make a tiny bit of content to your post.

Answer (score 1):

It is not theoretically impossible for protein to self-replicate. It just did not evolve to be a common mechanism. [Lee et al. 1996](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8700225) reports finding of a protein that can catalyze its own synthesis.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible indirectly in case of prion.See this [link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prion)

Comment: It would be helpful if you summarized the link in your answer, in case it is not available in the future